# Daisy Chaining MCP23017 & Addressing

Tags: gpio, i2c

I'm looking to daisy chain multiple MCP23017 chips (upward of 10) to essentially give me more IO to play with from my Pi.

I've started to work on the circuit diagram, but I'm really lost with all the addressing. Put simply, how do I layout these chips to allow me to one day be able to interface with each one from Python? (E.g. I want to make IC12 GPA3 high, then IC4 GPB5 High). If that makes sense?

Also, is the diagram below the standard way of daisy chaining? I can't find any examples online of this and I'm completely new to it.

[image]

(I've seen this: [How to get pin addresses on a MCP23017](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/how-to-get-pin-addresses-on-a-mcp23017) and it seems a great answer, it just sadly means very little to me)

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.  Each MCP23017 needs a unique I2C address.  There are three address lines so you can have a maximum of 8 chips on the bus (for 128 gpios).  What do you mean by daisy chain?

Comment: Perhaps I'm fundamentally misunderstanding this then. I need 96 IO and trying to find a way to achieve this. Could you possibly explain how you achieve 128 GPIO from just 8 Chips?

Comment: Each MCP23017 has 16 gpios.  8*16 = 128.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, apologies for my stupidity there! So with 8 chips, and with the default Python libraries, you'd wire all 8 chips to GPIO 3 & 5? Then set the A0, A1, A2 to VCC/GND to make 000, 001, 010 etc?

Comment: Ignorance != stupidity.  We are all ignorant.  Yes.  The I2C address for a MCP23017 is 0x20 + the address set on A0/1/2.  So to access the first 16 gpios use I2C address 0x20, the next 16 gpios use I2C address 0x21 etc.  All SDAs connected, all SCLs connected.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you! You've cleared up a few days worth of tangling myself up

Comment: I've been playing with one over the past few days.  http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=639691#p639691 may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here this is correct wring for Daisy chain:

[image: I/O Expander using 8 MCP23017 Daisy Chain]

Comment: Please explain why you think this is the correct wiring.

Comment: Well I tested it out so I do Know it works. Only thing I missed is the 10K Resistor attached to Reset PIN and then to VCC. Rest all is covered The whole system is in parallel connection and so have same Voltage. I have defined address to each MCP23017 and the along with the HEX above them. Also I tested it out on a bread board and works fine with NodeMCU. It doesn't matter if one uses RasPi or Arduino, it works fine with all. I'm a Developer so this may not follow the standards but I'm sure it's a working model